# How to remap topic's name?

Tags: urg-node, ros-kinetic, hokuyo, namespace, remap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! I'm using ROS kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04.

My 2D Lidar sensor Hokuyo requires urg_node to publish laser-scanned topic (its name is "/scan")

And I want to remap the name of this topic from "/scan" to "laser".

In detail, what I want to get is sensor_msgs/LaserSacn topic, whose name is "laser", and I also wish this laser topic should be in namespace of "/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front" .

I heard that  command should change it. But unfortunately, I run urg_node by rosrun, not roslaunch which means I can't modify it in launch file.

In this case, should I modify it in source node file(urg_node.cpp)?

And, once I change the topic's name to "/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front/laser ", it this laser-scanned topic could be in namespace of "/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/ laser_front" ? (The namespace "/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front" comes from other package.)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/333676/how-to-remap-topic%27s-name?/) by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2019-09-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-23**:
why not create a launch file for the node? Its only few lines and makes remapping and passing parameters way easier and cleaner.

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-23**:
Here is an [example](https://github.com/ros-drivers/urg_node/blob/indigo-devel/launch/urg_lidar.launch) of a launch file for the `urg_node` that you can use. Then all you need is to add the remap:

```
<remap from="scan" to="/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front/laser"/>
```

Of course you can make this way cleaner by using an arguments and launch the node within a namespace

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-09-23**:
Thank you for your quick answer. Then, by doing according to your advice, would the laser-scanned topic from urg_node be in namespace of /spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front?
Anyway, thanks for your really really quick feedback. :)

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-23**:
You can check the answer bellow, it contains an example launch file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an example launch file that you can use:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="my_namespace"           default="spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front" />
  <node ns="$(arg my_namespace)" name="urg_node" pkg="urg_node" type="urg_node" output="screen">
    <remap from="scan" to="laser"/>
  </node>
</launch>
```

The output (remapped) topic should have the namespace appended like this:

```
/spencer/perception_internal/people_detection/laser_front/laser
```

---

Originally posted by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) with karma: 1655 on 2019-09-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pavel92](https://answers.ros.org/users/32610/pavel92/) on 2019-09-23**:
Note that this will remap the `scan` to `namespace/laser` topic which means the `scan` topic will not exist any more under that name. In case you need to have both topics up and running check the [relay](http://wiki.ros.org/topic_tools/relay) node.

Also all other `topics/parameters` from `urd_node` will be now under the new namespace

**Comment by [kane_choigo](https://answers.ros.org/users/45263/kane_choigo/) on 2019-10-01**:
Thank you so much and really sorry for my late check. Though I didn't follow as it was, your advice was very helpful to me and I got the form of topics I want. I'll write about how I did below.
Anyway, I really really appreciate you.